# I couldn't scroll my textview automatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

hi I have an extension in the following code but it could not run for me :(

Actually I want to scroll my textView with a entered speed but I don't know how can I do this

```
    extension UITextView {
    func simple_scrollToBottom() {
        let textCount: Int = text.count
        guard textCount >= 1 else { return }
        scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: textCount - 1, length: 1))
    }
}
```

I used it as self.akor_goster.simple_scrollToBottom() in viewdidload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you would not want to call this from `viewDidLoad()`...

- At that point, auto-layout has not finished arranging everything in the view, frame and text view content is not yet ready.
- Also, you don't want to start an animation yet, because the view has not yet appeared.

So, if you want this to happen automatically, put the call in `viewDidAppear()`.

Second, you cannot control the scrolling speed when calling `scrollRangeToVisible()` -- but you can calculate the offset and animate that change with your desired speed.

Try this extension:

```
extension UITextView {
    func timedScrollToBottom(duration d: Double) {
        let y = contentSize.height - frame.size.height
        // if y is less than zero, all the text fits, so no scrolling needed
        guard y > 0 else {
            return
        }
        // Duration is in seconds
        UIView.animate(withDuration: d, animations: {
            self.contentOffset.y = y
        })
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.akor_goster.timedScrollToBottom(duration: 2.0)
}
```

Comment: thanks your answer, using animate is the best way as you said :)